# Chain Rule Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, proof-explanation

> [image]

This should be really simple, but I am not following where the Chain Rule is placed here.

If we set $f(tx_1, \dots, tx_n) = f(h_i(x_1,t), \dots, h_n(x_n,t))$, the total derivative is $$df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_i} \frac{\partial h_i}{\partial t} = \sum x_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_i} $$.
In the last step, as we setting $x_i = 1$?

If $f$ is smooth, wouldn't that imply all derivatives are smooth ($C^\infty$ smooth) and defined in the first  placed and hence $g_i$ must exist no matter what point we are at?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the chain rule.

$$\frac{\partial f(x(t))}{\partial t} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(x_i(t))}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial x_i(t)}{\partial t} $$

Here  $x_i(t) = tx_i $ and $ x(t) = (tx_1, ... tx_n)$

And so $$\frac{\partial x_i(t)}{\partial t}= x_i$$

Answer (score 0):

The second equality in the second displayed equation is true because of the chain rule. The functions $g_i$ so defined in the last line of the proof then satisfy the conclusion of the theorem (due to the second displayed equation).

It's true that $f$ is smooth and it's derivatives exist, but you want $g_i$ that specifically satisfy the first displayed equation. The initial condition on $f$ is for the fundamental theorem of calculus, used in the proof without comment.

Comment: Okay but that doesn't answer my question...

Comment: "I am not following where the Chain Rule is placed here." Then what did you mean by that? I did add another comment about the $g_i$.

Comment: Let's see, in the first line, they used Chain Rule. But my chain rule looks wrong compare to their's. Actually I accidentally reused $g$, that may have been the confusion. See edit.

Comment: Yes, I think I see your issue. There is an abuse of notation going on in the theorem. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is used for the partial derivative w.r.t. the first coordinate while $x_i$ are also used to denote points in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: If you re-write the theorem and denote points in $\mathbb R^n$ as $a_i$, you may find that your calculations agree with what's written and there's no more confusion.

Comment: Are you saying the last line is actually $g_i(a_i \dots a_n) = \dots$?

Comment: I'm saying that your $\frac{\partial}{\partial h_i}$ is their $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$, so I think that you don't disagree with the author of the theorem. Check equivalence by going back to the limit definition of partial derivative.